# Sharepoint Online upload files to library with PnP-JS-Core 2.0.7

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, office-365-developer, pnp, pnp-js-core

How do I upload a file with all properties or fields values to a sharepoint library?

I'm using PnP-JS-Core 2.0.7

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried till now ? What issues did you face ? Can share some related code of your attempts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below approach using the FileReader API :

Assume that you have html structure somewhat as mentioned below:

```
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" value="Upload File" />

<input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="UploadFiles()" />
```

Now, in your `UploadFiles` method, you can upload the file using `getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("server-relative-url").files.add` method and after that you get the uploaded files ID and then update its properties as below:

```
function UploadFiles() {
    var files = document.getElementById('uploadFile').files;
   //in case of multiple files,iterate or else upload the first file.
    var file = files[0]; 
    if (file!=undefined || file!=null){

    //assuming that the name of document library is Documents, change as per your requirement, 
    //this will add the file in root folder of the document library, if you have a folder named test, replace it as "/Documents/test"
    pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/Documents").files.add(file.name, file, true).then((result) => {
        console.log(file.name + " upload successfully!");
          result.file.listItemAllFields.get().then((listItemAllFields) => {
             // get the item id of the file and then update the columns(properties)
            pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Documents").items.getById(listItemAllFields.Id).update({
                        Title: "My New Title",
                        Description: "Here is a new description"
            }).then(r=>{
                        console.log(file.name + " properties updated successfully!");
            });           
        }); 
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: document.getElementById('uploadFile').files throws error for me saying "Property 'files' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement". When I try to use "<HTMLInputElement>" for casting, it throws error "JSX element type 'HTMLInputElement' is not a constructor function for JSX elements"..... Any ideas how to resolve this? Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is good example on the pnp js core github [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Files). Although example is in typescript you can get the idea which I have also used.