# 2016 - Upload multiple files with REST API and PNP

Tags: development, rest, 2016, pnp

I'm developing a multiple files upload form on SharePoint 2016.

My goal is to prevent duplicate files name, so my idea is to upload files in a document library, change a metadata of these files and then move these files to another document library changing their filenames to prevent duplicate.

So there are three main steps:

1) Files upload

2) Change files metadata

3) Move to another document library with a new file name (es.: myfile-timestamp.ext)

I've tried several ways, using PNP JS, but I did not find a solution.

This is my code that's is quite messy:

```
function UploadFiles() {
    var loadFiles = document.getElementById('loadFile').files;

    //in case of multiple files,iterate or else upload the first file.
    for (var i=0; i<=loadFiles.length;i++){
        var fileOgg = loadFiles[i];
        if (fileOgg!=undefined || fileOgg!=null){
            var nameFile = fileOgg.name;
            var timestamp = + new Date();
            var fileName = nameFile.substr(0, nameFile.lastIndexOf('.'));
            var newfileName = fileName + "-" + timestamp;
            var sourceFileUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl+"/Config/"+nameFile+"";
            var targetFileUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl+"/Attachments/"+nameFile.replace(fileName, newfileName)+"";

            new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { resolve (); })
            .then(UploadFilesStep.bind(null, fileOgg, true))
            .then(function(fileUpload) { 
                changeMetadata(fileUpload)
                .then(moveTo.bind(null, sourceFileUrl, targetFileUrl, nameFile, fileName, newfileName))
                .then(showSuccess) 
            });
        }
    }   
}

function UploadFilesStep (fileOgg, overwrite){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        pnp.setup({ headers: { "Cache-Control": "no-cache", }, });
        pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/testpcr/Config").files.add(fileOgg.name, fileOgg, overwrite).then(function(result) {
            console.log("FileUpload success");
            resolve(result);

        });   
    })
}

function changeMetadata(result) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        result.file.listItemAllFields.get().then(function(listItemAllFields) {
            // get the item id of the file and then update the columns(properties)
            pnp.setup({ headers: { "Cache-Control": "no-cache", }, });


pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Config").items.getById(listItemAllFields.Id).update({
                Number: ""+number+"",
            }).then(function(r){
                console.log(" properties updated successfully! Go to MoveTo");
                resolve();
            });
        });
    })
}

function moveTo(sourceFileUrl, targetFileUrl, nomeFile, fileNome, nuovoFileNome) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var headers = headers || {};
        var method = 'POST';
        headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
        var endpointUrl = siteurl2 + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + sourceFileUrl + "')/MoveTo(newurl='" + targetFileUrl + "',flags=1)";
        var payload;

        $.ajax({
            url: endpointUrl,
            type: method,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            cache: false,
            headers: headers,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                strResults += "";
                contatoreUpload = contatoreUpload + 1;
                resolve();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                strResults += "Error " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);;
                resolve();
            }
        });
    }); 
}
```

Do you have any example or different solution?

Comment: Before diving into this project, take a look at the existing SharePoint "Content Organizer" feature. It already supports moving files by metadata and add characters for creating unique names.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-the-Content-Organizer-to-route-documents-B0875658-69BC-4F48-ADDB-E3C5F01F2D9A

Answer (score 1):

The following function for your reference.

```
function UploadFiles() {
    var files = document.getElementById('exampleInputFile').files;
    var file = files[0]; //using File Api
    if (file!=undefined || file!=null){
        $pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/Documents").files.add(file.name, file, true).then(function (data) {
            var RelativeUrls=”/Documents/”+file.name;
            //Retrive Document which is uploaded. Start
            $pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(RelativeUrls).getItem().then(item => {
                //update start Below Call to Doc List will update the Row baseed on Item.ID
                $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Documents").items.getById(item.ID).update({
                    ColumnName: 'New Value'
                }).then(r => {
                    alert(file.name + " upload successfully!");
                    //move file if you want
                });//update end
            }); //Retrive Doc Info End
        }); //Upload Document End
    }
}
```

Check the thread below:

[SharePoint Online upload files to library with PnP-JS-Core 2.0.7](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/223172/sharepoint-online-upload-files-to-library-with-pnp-js-core-2-0-7)

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes upload works, but sometimes it returns: "Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user." (I think when it is trying to change the metadata).